# Convert array Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails

How can I convert `["90 99 8 9 11 22"]` to `["90", "99", "8", "9", "11", "22"]` in Ruby ?

Comment: `["90 99 8 9 11 22"][0].split`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`flat_map`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/flat_map) and [`split`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/split) it works with any number of items:

```rb
["90 99 8 9 11 22"].flat_map(&:split)
=> ["90", "99", "8", "9", "11", "22"]

> ["90 99 8 9 11 22", "1 2 3"].flat_map(&:split)
=> ["90", "99", "8", "9", "11", "22", "1", "2", "3"]
```